# Showing that this particular subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is non-triangulable.

Tags: general-topology, simplicial-complex

**Problem:** Let $S=\{(x,y):0\le y\le 1, x=0\;\, \text{or}\;\, x=1/n \quad\text{for}\; n=1,2,\cdots\}\cup ([0,1]\times {0}$), Show that $S$ is not triangulable.

Note: my definition for triangulation is that a set $X$ is triangulabe if there exists simplicial complex $K$ such that $|K|$ is homeomorphic to $X$

---

**My attempt:** So first thing I spotted was that $S$ is clearly closed, and hence compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Therefore, if a simplicial complex $|K|$ was homeomorphic to it, then it must also be compact, meaning that $|K|$ is finite. But here is one point of my concern: **I'm not supposed to know that all compact simplicial complexes are finite**, simply because I haven't yet covered it. Is there other way more elementary arguement to show that $|K|$ is finite, other than referring to the theorem?

Now there is explicit hint given in the problem:

*show that for any finite simplicial complex for any $x\in |K|$ and open set $U$ containing $x$ there is a connected open set $V$ such that $x\in V\subseteq U$*

Apart from the fact that I cannot see how this might help me solving problem, I also am a bit puzzled that it seems too much obvious for me to prove it: since $|K|$ can be embedded into finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}^n$ space, with standard metric on it we can always take $V$ to be a open ball around $x$, and we are done. **Is that right?**

I also see that $S$ is clearly path-connected, so my $|K|$ must be edge-connected and connected. But I seem to be stuck at this stage.

It would be really great if someone could explain how one would do this *with given hint*, if possible.

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: FYI, your space is also known as the [Comb space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space).

Comment: Thanks for that! I guess terminology does make sense, though I thought it was more like barcode for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This space (the comb space) is not locally connected: any small enough neighborhood of a point like $(0,1/2)$ splits into several components (try discs, for instance). The hint you are given is that simplicial complexes are locally connected: each point has a open nbhd basis of connected sets. Hence the comb cannot be simplicial.

Comment: Is that because any ball around $(0,1/2)$ must contain some element from "other lines" so they are disconnected? Also, do you think my proof for locally connectedness of $|K|$ look alright?

Comment: Yes to the first. Concerning the second, it's not just metrizability. This depends on the particular nature of simplicial complexes. For instance look at the edge of a 2-complex, you must put togheter some "half-balls" from the faces meeting at the edge. The point is that every face is homeo to an afine space, and you glue them carefully.

Comment: Ah, okay, so like for every vertices/edges/faces of simplices, we can form a open disc around them with whatever central angle (as we can deform them) so that when glued together, form a open ball in |K|, and we can choose radius to be small enough and so on, is that right?

Comment: I think you understand it, yes!

Comment: alright, thanks I got it!